# Why does root not have /usr/local in path?

Tags: root, path

I've noticed that the default path for root on my of my vm's and servers do not include /usr/local/bin

```
sudo -s  
echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Whereas normal users on the server do have /usr/local/bin

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/sowen/bin
```

Why would root not need /usr/local in the path?

Where is the default path for a user defined?

Comment: On what OS is it? Most do have `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/local/bin` on root's default path, but there are exceptions.

Comment: Just encountered a strange difference between two RHEL 6.4 VMs (one with `/usr/local/bin` and one without). And the one with `/usr/local/bin`, I couldn't find where it was being set.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because it isn't set up in the relevant shell startup files for root.

Traditionally, `/usr/local` has been used for unofficial, locally installed software (often to override buggy/broken/limited "official" versions; a friend quipped that the first step when a new Sun arrived was `GNU > /usr/local`). As `root` is all-powerful, any mistake or misdesign in the programs it runs can be fatal. It stands to reason that running e.g. a local, experimental version of `make` by root should be treated with caution. Better have it go the extra step of giving an explicit path.